# Is possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 on ACER V5-571-53314G50 ULTRABOOK?

Tags: installation, acer, ultrabook

Is possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 on ACER V5-571-53314G50 ULTRABOOK? My specifications are:

```
Display: 15.6" 1.366 x 768 WXGA HD; LED, Acer CineCrystal™ 
CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3317U, 2cores, 1.7GHz, turbo @ 2.6GHz, 22nm; 3MB Intel® Smart cache; Hyper-Threading; Ivy Bridge 
Chipset: Intel® HM77 Express 
Ultra Thin and Light design 
Memory: 4GB DDR3 
HDD: 500GB SATA 
VGA: nVidia® GeForce® GT 620M 1GB DDR3 + Intel HD Graohics 4000 
ODD: DVD±RW Super Multi Dual Layer 
WiFi: Acer InviLink™ Nplify™, IEEE 802.11a/g/n; Wi-Fi 
Bluetooth 4,0 
Network Adapter: 10/100/1000Mbps 
Ports: HDMI, VGA, USB 3.0 x 1, USB 2.0 x2 
Card Reader 2in1 
Camera: Acer Crystal Eye HD 1.3MP 720p 
Speakers: 2.0 Dolby® Advanced Audio® v2 Surround; High Definition 
OS: Linux Linpus™
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check Ubuntu's [Hardware Compability List](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport)
. Even though, your device is not listed in the list, there is a high probability that your device will be supported by Ubuntu.